# Make sure to register a handler via on<CheckIfFavoriteMovieEvent>((event, emit) {...}) error

Tags: flutter, dart

Good day, my codes are as you see below:

```
class FavoriteBloc extends Bloc<FavoriteEvent, FavoriteState> {
  final SaveMovie saveMovie;
  final GetFavoriteMovies getFavoriteMovies;
  final DeleteFavoriteMovie deleteFavoriteMovie;
  final CheckIfFavoriteMovie checkIfFavoriteMovie;

  FavoriteBloc({
    required this.saveMovie,
    required this.getFavoriteMovies,
    required this.deleteFavoriteMovie,
    required this.checkIfFavoriteMovie,
  }) : super(FavoriteInitial());

  @override
  Stream<FavoriteState> mapEventToState(
      FavoriteEvent event,
      ) async* {
    if (event is ToggleFavoriteMovieEvent) {
      if (event.isFavorite) {
        await deleteFavoriteMovie(MovieParams(event.movieEntity.id));
      } else {
        await saveMovie(event.movieEntity);
      }
      final response =
      await checkIfFavoriteMovie(MovieParams(event.movieEntity.id));
      yield response.fold(
            (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
            (r) => IsFavoriteMovie(r),
      );
    } else if (event is LoadFavoriteMovieEvent) {
      yield* _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies();
    } else if (event is DeleteFavoriteMovieEvent) {
      await deleteFavoriteMovie(MovieParams(event.movieId));
      yield* _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies();
    } else if (event is CheckIfFavoriteMovieEvent) {
      final response = await checkIfFavoriteMovie(MovieParams(event.movieId));
      yield response.fold(
            (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
            (r) => IsFavoriteMovie(r),
      );
    }
  }

  Stream<FavoriteState> _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies() async* {
    final Either<AppError, List<MovieEntity>> response =
    await getFavoriteMovies(NoParams());

    yield response.fold(
          (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
          (r) => FavoriteMoviesLoaded(r),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error :
**Unhandled Exception: Bad state: add(CheckIfFavoriteMovieEvent) was called without a registered event handler.
Make sure to register a handler via on((event, emit) {...})**

I would be very grateful if you can help me for the solution of this error I have written. Many thanks to everyone who helps now

I used many artificial intelligence tools to solve the problem, but it did not give me the solution I wanted.

Comment: You should register events in the body of ther Bloc's Constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```dart
class FavoriteBloc extends Bloc<FavoriteEvent, FavoriteState> {
  final SaveMovie saveMovie;
  final GetFavoriteMovies getFavoriteMovies;
  final DeleteFavoriteMovie deleteFavoriteMovie;
  final CheckIfFavoriteMovie checkIfFavoriteMovie;

  FavoriteBloc({
    required this.saveMovie,
    required this.getFavoriteMovies,
    required this.deleteFavoriteMovie,
    required this.checkIfFavoriteMovie,
  }) : super(FavoriteInitial()) {
    on<FavoriteEvent>((event, emit) async {
      if (event is ToggleFavoriteMovieEvent) {
        if (event.isFavorite) {
          await deleteFavoriteMovie(MovieParams(event.movieEntity.id));
        } else {
          await saveMovie(event.movieEntity);
        }
        final response =
            await checkIfFavoriteMovie(MovieParams(event.movieEntity.id));

        emit(response.fold(
          (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
          (r) => IsFavoriteMovie(r),
        ));
      } else if (event is LoadFavoriteMovieEvent) {
        _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies(emit);
      } else if (event is DeleteFavoriteMovieEvent) {
        await deleteFavoriteMovie(MovieParams(event.movieId));
        _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies(emit);
      } else if (event is CheckIfFavoriteMovieEvent) {
        final response = await checkIfFavoriteMovie(MovieParams(event.movieId));

        emit(response.fold(
          (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
          (r) => IsFavoriteMovie(r),
        ));
      }
    });
  }

  void _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies(Emitter emit) async {
    final Either<AppError, List<MovieEntity>> response =
        await getFavoriteMovies(NoParams());

    emit(response.fold(
      (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
      (r) => FavoriteMoviesLoaded(r),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, all the errors have been resolved.

Comment: @junior you're welcome. Please, consider visiting https://bloclibrary.dev/#/ .